# Wrong number of the element in Adapter at GridView

Tags: java, android, baseadapter

I created my own adapter that extend BaseAdapter and I use it for GridView. I want to get the number of element and put it into TextView. I did it in my adapter:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View gridView;

        if(convertView == null){
            gridView = new View(context);

            gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_element, null);

            ImageView logo = (ImageView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.grid_logo);


            TextView tv = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.grid_textView1);
            tv.setText(level+position);
        }
        else
            gridView = convertView;

        return gridView;
    }
```

It seems to be good until I get elements that are not in the screen in launch:
[image]

The position is like reseted.
How can I do it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were not setting the TextView properly when convertView was not null. Try this:

```
if (convertView == null) {
    gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_element, null);
} else {
    gridView = convertView;
}

ImageView logo = (ImageView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.grid_logo);

TextView tv = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.grid_textView1);
tv.setText(level + position);
```

Answer (score 1):

May help new Visitors.

You have to know two main things :

1. You need to check if `convertView` is null, in order to know if that row in your list is not created yet (`convertView = null`) or is being recycled by the adapter (`convertView != null`). This is called the [`Recycling`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14108676/2178259) process.
2. Another important thing to know is the [`View Holder Pattern`](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder). Calling `findViewById()` on each row of `getView()` method is to heavy for list populating and slows down scrolling performance. To avoid that, create a static class with some views as class fields. Than use `findViewById()` if the view is being created (`convertView == null`), and get it back from `getTag()` method when it's being recycled

`

```
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView text;
    ImageView icon;
}

ViewHolder holder;
if(convertView == null) {
    convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, root); 
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listitem_image);
    holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listitem_text);
    holder.timestamp = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listitem_timestamp);
    holder.progress = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.progress_spinner);
    convertView.setTag(holder);
}

holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

// Set here your view's content : 
holder.text.setText("Sample"); 
// ...
```